# Classic ASP Session Variables Lost on Windows Server 2008 R2 / IIS 7

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic, vbscript, windows-server-2008

We transferred our existing website which is running on a Server 2003 machine using iis6 and coded with classic asp to a Server 2008 64 bit machine using iis7 and classic asp.  The only changes to the pages were for our calls to a Universe db, which need a new connection string .  We tested all the pages within the department running 4-5 users and all went well.  When we made it live for everyone (between 40 and 100 users) users were losing their session variables some immediately and others after 3 minutes.

Is there a setting in iis7 that could be throttling the amout of memory allotted for session variables?  Or does anyone have any other ideas as to what may be happening.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bad driver; crashing on 64-bit OS.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem and apparently resolved by changing the application pool to Classic. NET AppPool, not yet tested my entire application, but apparently resolved

Answer (score 0):

I can't test it here and now, but if I remember correctly you have to give the asp application it's own application pool (see the appropriate section in the IIS settings).

Comment: @tjsimmons Any news on this ?

Comment: Yeah, completely forgot this asked here. It turns out the driver we were using to talk to UniVerse was 32-bit, and crashing under the load of the users on the 64-bit server, and due to the crashes the app pool was restarting itself.