# Classic ASP Session/IIS Reset Bug in IIS 7?

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic

I have an application in classic asp running on IIS 7.  The website uses global ASA (`Application_OnStart` and `Session_OnEnd`, the others are not being used)

The problem is this.  When one user logs in/out, sometimes the entire site does some sort of IIS reset and all the visitors of that site will have their sessions all reset. If any visitor was logged, it kicks them out and they have to login again.

There is some sort of activity triggering this mass session reset, or better yet, IIS reset, because it only happens sometimes.  I am not sure what could be causing it.. Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe same problem as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3721603/583530) ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the  "Recycling..." action on the relevant Application pool in IIS Manager to check the Recycling conditions.

Anything that causes recycling of the application pool will result in the loss of all current sessions.  Use the same dialog to turn on logging of recycles (if not already on).

Use event log to track any recycles and their cause.

Comment: ok, recycyling was set to on.  i disabled it.  but, does disabling it do anything it shouldn't be?  do i have to recycle all app pools as best practice at somepoint?  thanks btw.

Answer (score 0):

Internet Information Services (IIS) application pools can be periodically recycled to avoid unstable states that can lead to application crashes, hangs, or memory leaks. Please check [this event id on technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc735034%28v=ws.10%29.aspx). It explains a bit more.

If you disable recycle settings and your application is buggy then there is lots of chances of your website getting down. Recently I also increased the session timeout of my website but it was timing out 12:45 irrespective of ilde time out. Hence I shifted the recycle settings to 20:00 during non buiness hours. So that it can clear all the unwanted app pools.